# Question about the property 'one-to-one mapping' of the Fourier transform.

Tags: fourier-transform

I am a student studying on Electrical engineering. Recently, I am anxious about the fourier transform's mapping property during proving the relationship between bessel function and fourier transform of U-shape function.

My question is

> If $G(f)$ exists such that $\mathcal{F}\left\{g(t)\right\}$ exists, where $\mathcal{F}$ represents the fourier transform, i.e., $$ G(f)=\mathcal{F}\left\{g(t)\right\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t) \exp\left(-j 2 \pi f t\right) dt,$$
>   then $g(t)$ exists and it is $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{G(f)\right\}=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(f)\exp\left(j2\pi ft\right)df$.

That is, when proving that $g(t)$ and $G(f)$ are pair in Fourier-transformation-sense, is it enough to prove only one direction either $\left(g\to G\right)$ or $(g\leftarrow G)$ without needing to prove both directions $(g\leftrightarrow G)$?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Fourier inversion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem.

Comment: @User8128 Wow Thank you very much. I don't know why I cannot find this page!! Both $f$ and its Fourier transform are absolutely integrable in the Lebesgue sense and $f$ is continuous at the point $x$, proving one direction is enough!! Thank you

Comment: Would you mind to clean-up your notation? It would considerably improve the readability of your question! There are $x,t,f$ around as variables, and the functions $f,g$. (May be choose $\omega$ instead of $2\pi f$ in the argument of the exponential?)

Comment: @Hanno Thanks to you, I notice that my notation is wrong, and I edited! thank you